# why life time of DBContext object is very short

Tags: asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

as per microsoft documentation " A DbContext instance is designed to be used for a single unit-of-work. This means that the lifetime of a DbContext instance is usually very short." what life time i choose scoped,singleton or transient? what problem occured if i use DBcontext object as singleton

Comment: It says further down the page where you quoted that from. It isn't thread safe and it can lead to memory leaks. So why would you want it as a singleton? If you are trying to inject it into a singleton service you should create local scopes instead.

Answer (score 0):

When you call

```
services.AddDbContext<MyContext>(options => { });
```

The `DbContext` will be registered as a scoped service. So a new instance will be created for each and every request.

This is the most flexible approach, as it allows you to configure a different ConnectionString, based on the tenant that's associated with eg the `HttpContext` (for example: a different ConnectionString depending on the `HttpContext.Request.Host`)

Answer (score 0):

Reusing same instance of `DbContext` will cause bugs: calling `SaveChanges` will save ALL tracked objects modified by a different consumers of `DbContext`.

If you worry about performance you may take a look at [DbContext pooling](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/performance/advanced-performance-topics?tabs=with-di%2Cwith-constant)